# Can you use the width of a div to calcuate the Left property?

Tags: css

I am trying to set the left to be half of the width but I am unsure how to do that.

I figured you could use Calc() but I don't know how I would get the width property (set dynamically with slick.js)

```
.qpStar {
    position: relative;
    left: ???;
    top: 2px;
}
```

I am trying to get a span to align on the left of the div using the left property.  It starts at the center of the div

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `left: 50%` takes 50% of the offset parent.

But you might set `transform: translateX(50%)` instead of `left`.

Answer (score 2):

Try This ....

```
 .qpStar {
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;  
        top: 2px;
    }
```

Another Way...

```
.qpStar {
        position: relative;
        transform: translateX(50%);
        top: 2px;
    }
```